# Image pre-loading for scroller has issues with chrome and webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, preload

I'm currently modifying the `smoothDivScroll` jquery plugin and im finding that it has issues within Chrome and Safari.

After much googling and StackOverflow searching I can attribute this to being an issue with the way image dimensions are calculated within Chrome and Safari.

The issue is, that in chrome and Safari, the images are not yet visible as they appear within a scroller and the overall width of the scroller cannot be worked out in these browsers and generates a series of white space.

The conclusion i have come to is that the images need to be preloaded for it to be able to calculate the dimensions within.

Here is the offending code:

```
// Add up the total width of all the items inside the scrollable area
el.data("scrollableArea").children(o.countOnlyClass).each(function () {
    // Check to see if the current element in the loop is the one where the scrolling should start
    if ($(this).is('img')) {

        if ((o.startAtElementId.length !== 0) && (($(this).attr("id")) === o.startAtElementId)) {
            el.data("startingPosition", tempScrollableAreaWidth);
            foundStartAtElement = true;
        }
        var ow = $(this).outerWidth(true);

        if (ow == 0) ow = 1 * $(this).find("img").attr("width");

        el.data("allImages").each(function () {
            var ths = $(this);
            var kx = eh / 1 * ths.attr("height");
            ths.attr({
                width: kx / ths.attr("width"),
                height: eh
            })
        })
        //tempScrollableAreaWidth +" "+ $(this).outerWidth(true) + " "
        tempScrollableAreaWidth = tempScrollableAreaWidth + ow;

    }
});
```

I've tried preloading the images externally before this script runs, however chrome and safari will only run them occasionally and the preloaded images never seem to make it.

I'm wondering if someone can show me how to make these images preload within this script so the image dimensions are accessible via the calculation that is processing at the end ie `tempScrollableAreaWidth`.

Answer (score 0):

Use image onload function within that function refresh or create your scroller.